# cmake, how to specify the output directory

Tags: cmake

I'm using cmake to generate a VS2017 solution (and projects...), I try to generate everything in a different folder.

I used both the command line and different variables, but no way, it generate in the "source" folder !

Here are some examples of what I tried:

```
cd source
cmake -B../build ...

cd build
cmake ../source

cmake --build "../build"

cmake -Dxxx=../build
```

Any idea ? all theses solutions are expected to generate in the build folder !

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. You are trying an out-of-source build, right? Then CMake will generate the same folder structure as your source directory, and put its file there. What do you expect? And how does the result differ from your expectations?

Comment: I try to put all the generated files in another folder than the one where the cmakelists.txt file is !! By example, I need the .sln file in the ../build folder

Comment: `build` is part of your project, right? Create a now folder outside your project, switch to this directory and run 'cmake <path-to-source-dir>'

Answer (score 0):

Once you have performed *in-source* build (in `source` directory), it is impossible to build the project *out-of-source*: every such attempt will modify in-source build.

You need to clear build files (`CMakeCache.txt`, probably some other ones) in source directory before using out-of-source builds.

Comment: Thanks, you're right but it is not the problem. I delete everything each time !

Comment: If so, you should be able to build *out-of-source*. E.g., by `cd build && cmake ../source`. Does this command work correctly for you?

Comment: Then you have not cleaned the source directory. List all files and directories here, and remove all which you haven't created.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with:

```
cd VSBuild
cmake ../
```

instead of

```
cd VSBuild
cmake ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?  This will put all the build files under "out"

```
$ cmake -H. -Bout
```

To execute:

```
$ cmake --build out
```